# How to detect if a file is being included or directly ran

Tags: php, include

I have a php file that I include in my php script, but I don't want people to be able to directly run the file(without being included).
How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the included scripts **not accessible via HTTP at all**. E.g. by protecting the subfolder or moving them above the document root.

If you cannot do that, `define()` something like `IS_INCLUDED` in your main script and `exit;` if this constant is not `defined()` in your included script.

Comment: I suppose many webapps chose the later optionly soley for the purpose of simplifying installation.  Keeping included scripts outside of docroot is definitely a better solution, when you can.

Comment: The `.htaccess` solution is pretty simple, too - and most people are using Apache anyway.

Comment: For the first solution, it might be dangerous, if you don't implement the second too. If you're in a shared environment, the server can have its configuration changed (also erroneously) in a way that the subfolder protection no longer works, or you can move your script to another server which has different security policies and you might not be well prepared about it. Better write strong code, not relying on some server features.

Comment: `.htaccess` won't help you on the off chance someone turns off AllowOverride, though.

Comment: I think you get a 500 error if AllowOverride is off. So it would also effectively lock out people. @Giacomo: That's like expecting PHP to be disabled accidentally, resulting in people being able to view your PHP sourcecode including database login data...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: not really. It would just make it a bit stronger towards unpredicted configuration changes that may happen in more cases than the "disabled php" scenario.

Comment: You can also play with apache / nginx `php_value auto_prepend_file '/path/to/prepend.php'`. In that file you can play with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and `in_array` function and viola. Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

Checking if the script is the parent of the PHP process might not be the best idea for preventing users of requesting an include file directly. But it can be handy in many other cases i.e. AJAX modules etc. I'm not gonna start a new topic by this.

```
if (__FILE__ == get_included_files()[0])
// Doesn't work with PHP prepend unless calling [1] instead.

if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
// May not work on Windows due to mixed DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (machine specific)

if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
// Doesn't work with files with the same basename but different paths

if (defined('FLAG_FROM_A_PARENT'))
// Works in all scenarios but I personally dislike this

if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
// Should work flawlessly
```

Keep in mind some machines that use virtual paths may return different paths in different php components. realpath() is your friend for this.

Comment: I have successfully used the `if(strtolower($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) === strtolower(__FILE__)) {` version in windows.  I use it when I want to test a file that I generally require_once().

Comment: In your second option, the script_filename variable had the whole path + filename already in it. I don't know if that's the same for others....

Answer (score 3):

I use a *sentinel constant*, defined in the "including" script, and the "included" script looks for it.

Example:

```
/* main.php */
define('SENTINEL', 1);
include "included.inc.php"

/* included.inc.php */
if (!defined('SENTINEL')) die("Wanted to be smart?? Nice try.");
```

Answer (score 3):

2 solutions for a good protection:

1. **Apache**

with *htaccess*:

```
RedirectMatch 404 "\.(sql|sh|java|class|inc\.php)$"
```

Or in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#...
RedirectMatch 404 "\.(sql|sh|java|class|inc\.php)$"
#...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then name your file like this: `myInternalFileIncludeOnly.inc.php`

1. **PHP**

With this sample code, PHP is able to detect include:

```
if( get_included_files()[0] == __FILE__ ){
    echo '2.php direct access';
}else{
    echo '2.php was included';
}
```

**EDIT**:
See Tim answer, so if you have a prepend include (cf php.ini) use this:

```
if(
    (!ini_get('auto_prepend_file') && get_included_files()[0] === __FILE__)
    ||
    ini_get('auto_prepend_file') && (($__FILE__=str_replace('\\','/',__FILE__)) === str_replace('\\','/',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) || $__FILE__ === str_replace('\\','/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) )
)
    echo '2.php direct access',"\n";
```

Comment: I always use get_included_files() myself, but I discovered it does not work on machines who are using php prepend.

Comment: See my edit. Is it correct for Windows ? But this new version takes more computations...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this pattern in some applications:

1. Main, directly run file runs `define('SOMETHING', 'SOMEVALUE');`
2. Included file starts with `if(!defined('SOMETHING')) return;`

Answer (score 0):

Included PHP files should contain class/function/variable definitions, not inline logic/output.

Running them directly is then, essentially, a no-op.

Comment: That's a good point but sometimes it can be useful to put some code on it. I used `include` also for getting the requested page contents w/o using database or other complex stuff (templates, etc...)

Comment: @Giacomo: I don't understand your use case. Non-encapsulated code is _ew_, leading to problems just like the one you're asking about.

Comment: -1 as this is a convenient way to load a page both using ajax and natively. The answer is a bit hasty. if (my_is_included()) my_output_header().

Comment: @tim: It may be "convenient" but it's nasty, messy and dangerous. You should have _one_ entrypoint with a controller class that includes other scripts it needs and invokes functions in them to parse input and print output. Not these encapsulationless function calls that randomly output headers all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and already answered, but nothing works for me nicely. So I found the following solution and like to post it here!

**It also works in cli:**

```
if ( __FILE__ == __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ) {

  die('<tt><h1>You cannot access the specified file!');

}
```

Comment: there could be files with the same name but different paths, as stated in the other answer

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for the hint, I updated it to a version that also works in cli ;-)

Comment: good idea. is realpath() necessary tho? __FILE__ is already the absolute file path. also you might want to combine $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead of __DIR__.

Comment: @Brad You are right, realpath() is not needed (ich changed that already) but on my MAMP System the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not set on CLI so i need my solution to make it work - cheers

Comment: ah yes of course. I'm using debug_backtrace (added my own answer) which works in CLI too and tells you who included the file.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use the debug backtrace .

```
$caller = debug_backtrace()[0] ?? null;
if ($caller && in_array($caller['function'] ?? 'unknown', ['include', 'require', 'include_once', 'require_once'])) {
    echo 'This file was included/required by ' . $caller['file'];
}
```

No need to define constants in all your other files before including it or picking apart the request URI or falling into any traps with bad file name comparisons.

Plus this will also work for PHP run via commandline.

#### Note that I answered the question title and not the use case.

For the reason **why** you want to detect this, the better answer is:

Move the sensitive PHP files outside the public space.

```
/website/
|- public/
  |- public files...
|- source
  |- private include files...
```

If your web server forces you to have all files in the public folder, then create a subfolder and then use a .htaccess file to block anyone from accessing anything inside it.

```
#inside of '/website/public/source/.htaccess`
Deny from all
```